# Delete specific rows from SQL Server Error Log

Tags: sql-server, logging, delete-row

Is it possible to delete specific rows from the SQL Server Error Log?
We had a bug that caused the log to fill up with tons of identical error messages and we want to get rid of them by deleting them.

Is it possible?

We do not want to delete the full log, just the ones containing "Process ID ** was killed".

Comment: Don't think so, not without manually editing the error log files (inadvisable). Why do you care, it will just roll over anyway?

Comment: Are you cycling your error log on a regular basis? If not, I'd suggest doing that (it's as easy as setting up a SQL Agent job to call `sp_cycle_errorlog` and adding a schedule to it). But even if you don't want to do that, you can call that proc manually.